# How to display current location blue point without setMyLocationEnabled true?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-gps, currentlocation

I am using google map V2 and i need to display custom image button click to get current location with blue point and no display to setMyLocationEnabled button. And already false this method but current location is display but blue point is not display.

[image]

```
  googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: did you added permission in AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Yes..I added !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well i guess you have your current latitude and longitude using the gps. After that it is really simple. You make a marker object and add it to the map like this.

```
MarkerOptions yourMakerOptions;
Marker yourMarker;


    yourMakerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    yourMakerOptions.title("Title");
    yourMakerOptions.snippet("");
    yourMarkerOptions.position(new LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude));
    //Set your marker icon using this method.
    yourMakerOptions.icon();
```

Finally add it to the map.

```
yourMarker = map.addMarker(yourMakerOptions);
```

To move the map to the current location call this method in onClickListener of your button.

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude), 14));
```

Hope this helps.

Try this :

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Okay. but it is no display blue point just add only marker. Another solution ?

Comment: Yes...perfect...this code..Thank You So Much..
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

For getting complete information about Current location [Read this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location)

add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: @NajibPuthawala did you added above permission ?

Comment: but in your screenshot blue dot is appearing.

Comment: Yes... I added the permission in Manifest and screen shot just shown u for only need for blue point..without my location button.

Comment: are your testing the app on real device ?

Comment: Yes... I tested device Nexus 5 Google. It is not display only blue point as current location point.

Comment: @NajibPuthawala i read [this article](https://androidforums.com/threads/no-blue-direction-arrow-in-google-maps-in-lolipop-5.886225/) he has same issue on Nexus 5. so he just change the language to English now bule dot appear. read this. hope it will help to u.